# How can I change ToolBar foreground color using CSS e4?

Tags: eclipse, e4

I am trying to change a foreground color (or text) of ToolBar item using CSS

```css
#amap-toolbar-0 {
    background-color: black;
    foreground-color:white; 
}
```

or

```css
ToolBar {
    background-color: black;
    foreground-color:white; 
}
```

Both are only able to change the background color of ToolBar. The text color is still shown in black.

How do I solve this ?

**UPDATE**

```css
#amap-toolbar-0 {
    background-color: black;
    color:white;    
}
```

The font is still in black color.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce this, 'color' works fine for me.

Comment: any configuration I possibly missing ?

Comment: Added details of Windows bug to answer (I am using Mac OS X).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS value for foreground color is just `color` so:

```css
#amap-toolbar-0 {
    background-color: black;
    color:white; 
}
```

This works on Mac OS X but there is an Eclipse bug [401227](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401227) which seems to be saying this does not work on Windows.

Comment: Tried that but the color is still black.